# Is Flurry and Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT compatible?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, flurry, flurry-analytics

### How to fix Flurry SDK load failure?

#### Setup

Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT project with [SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b)

Using SQLite forces you to make your project build to either:

- ARM
- x86

#### Code

In the load of a view model I call:

```
FlurryWP8SDK.Api.LogEvent(eventName,true);
```

And gives exception

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\ *number*.Release_AnyCPU.Barnstokkr\WMAppManifest.xml'

It seems that Flurry searches in an incorrect area for the Manifest, since it isn't `AnyCPU` but `ARM`.

#### Question

Is there a way around this? Is there a way to tell Flurry to search for the Manifest somewhere else?

If Flurry eventually gets the correct path, will it even still work on the issue that the manifest does not define the `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE` capability anymore (as specified by the [documentation](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart/Windows))?

#### Additional

I saw this [question on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b9b43f8a-4122-4f6d-8607-dacdf265b012/is-the-flurry-support-for-windows-phone-81?forum=wpdevelop), but even after the upgrade from 3.1.1 to 3.1.2 using [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FlurrySDK/), the issue still persists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the upgrade from Windows Phone 8 to Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) it seems I didn't read the description of the package (or it was added later)

- `8.1 (Silverlight)`

Thus no, Flurry does not support Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT; only Silverlight

[image: NuGet Flurry]

Maybe in a next version, but not in 3.1.2